# String truncation in qt based on width

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

Assume I have a string in a rectangle which I am able to resize. Given that I know the width of the ractangle after resize takes place how can I find the last character of the string that if I truncate the string to that character it will fit into the new (resized) rectangle ? Currently I have solved my problem in a loop until I match the desired rectangle width by adding characters incrementally. Is there a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QFontMetrics`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html):

```
QFontMetrics metrics(labelText->font());
int textInPixeles = metrics.width(labelText->text());
```

or you can use [`QFontMetrics::boundingRect`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2).

Having widget width, `textInPixeles` and width of last character of your text you can estimate what you need.